# OpenCV unexpected segfault

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

I am trying to do some matrix operations in openCV for the first time, and I have problems in working with matrices. I get a segfault on a similar function as below.

```
void foo()
{
    cv::Mat m1(2, 1, CV_32F);
    m1.at<float>(0) = 1;
    m1.at<float>(1) = 2;

    //The following line gives me a segfault
    double norm = cv::norm(m1, cv::NORM_L2);
}
```

Why do I get a segfault on the line above? I can't seem to find any uninitialized or unallocated arrays. What do I miss?

EDIT:// Alright I found the problem. Apparently ubuntu 14.04 has openCV auto installed in Version 2.4.8 where I used Version 3.1.0. The program then linked the wrong libraries for the includes that I used (2.4.8 libs and 3.1.0 includes). I did not think to check the libs in the first place.

Comment: This code is perfectly fine. You probably messed up configuration. Be sure that you configured correctly OpenCV, not to mix debug/release libs, same compiler as your project, etc...